# pip installations hang (Windows 10) (python 3.10)

Tags: pip, windows-10, python-3.10

I recently reinstalled python because weird stuff was happening with imports and virtual environments.

Now, when I try to install a library -- kivy, for example -- this happens:

```
(env) C:\Users\Marcels friend\Desktop\sdf>py -m pip install kivy[base] kivy_examples
Collecting kivy[base]
  Using cached Kivy-2.0.0.tar.gz (23.7 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\Marcels friend\Desktop\sdf\env\Scripts\python.exe' 'C:\Users\Marcels friend\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-standalone-pip-820ai__z\__env_pip__.zip\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\Marcels friend\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-p3plnhu0\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'cython>=0.24,<=0.29.21,!=0.27,!=0.27.2' 'kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev~=0.3.1; sys_platform == "win32"' 'kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.3.1; sys_platform == "win32"' 'kivy_deps.glew_dev~=0.3.0; sys_platform == "win32"' 'kivy_deps.gstreamer~=0.3.1; sys_platform == "win32"' 'kivy_deps.sdl2~=0.3.1; sys_platform == "win32"' 'kivy_deps.glew~=0.3.0; sys_platform == "win32"'
       cwd: None
  Complete output (10 lines):
  Collecting setuptools
    Using cached setuptools-58.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (946 kB)
  Collecting wheel
    Using cached wheel-0.37.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
  Collecting cython!=0.27,!=0.27.2,<=0.29.21,>=0.24
    Using cached Cython-0.29.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl (974 kB)
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev~=0.3.1 (from versions: none)
  ERROR: No matching distribution found for kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev~=0.3.1
  WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.3; however, version 21.2.4 is available.
  You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\Marcels friend\Desktop\sdf\env\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/12/96/091ddacafb84dd18555a32d860dbfaf9c806147aa30c6f3c8b93cb7bab97/Kivy-2.0.0.tar.gz#sha256=d25e44eb44e43762b2fd0c5874e51954e0f1181fd9800d8a6756be6d084812d8 (from https://pypi.org/simple/kivy/). Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\Marcels friend\Desktop\sdf\env\Scripts\python.exe' 'C:\Users\Marcels friend\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-standalone-pip-820ai__z\__env_pip__.zip\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\Marcels friend\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-p3plnhu0\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'cython>=0.24,<=0.29.21,!=0.27,!=0.27.2' 'kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev~=0.3.1; sys_platform == "win32"' 'kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.3.1; sys_platform == "win32"' 'kivy_deps.glew_dev~=0.3.0; sys_platform == "win32"' 'kivy_deps.gstreamer~=0.3.1; sys_platform == "win32"' 'kivy_deps.sdl2~=0.3.1; sys_platform == "win32"' 'kivy_deps.glew~=0.3.0; sys_platform == "win32"' Check the logs for full command output.
  Using cached Kivy-1.11.1.tar.gz (23.6 MB)
```

At this point, it just gets stuck. Doesn't matter if I'm doing it from within or without a virtual environment. I've tried pip-installing two other libraries: requests, which worked; and matplotlib, which didn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know why it is getting stuck, but what I see is that you are using python 3.10, which is so fresh, that I  had to go check to see if it is already released (it is! 5 days ago!).

`kivy` does not have a wheel for 3.10, so it is trying to build one from the source, and crashes because of the missing kivy-deps.gstreamer-dev dependency, which is binary only and not available for python 3.10.

I deduce, that it is unlikely that you will be able to install `kivy` with python 3.10. Try 3.9?

Comment: 3.9 worked. Thank you, internet person.